# RNG Challenge Python

Tags: python, random, ctf

I am trying to solve a CTF challenge in which the goal is to guess the generated number. Since the number is huge and you only have 10 attempts per number, I don't think you can apply binary search or any kind of algorithm to solve it, and that it has something to do with somehow getting the seed of the random function and being able to generate the next number, but I have no idea on where to start to get the correct seed. Do you have any idea?
Here's the code of the challenge:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import signal
import os
import random

TIMEOUT = 300

assert("FLAG" in os.environ)
FLAG = os.environ["FLAG"]
assert(FLAG.startswith("CCIT{"))
assert(FLAG.endswith("}"))


def handle():
    for i in range(625):
        print(f"Round {i+1}")
        guess_count = 10
        to_guess = random.getrandbits(32)
        while True:
            print("What do you want to do?")
            print("1. Guess my number")
            print("2. Give up on this round")
            print("0. Exit")
            choice = int(input("> "))
            if choice == 0:
                exit()
            elif choice == 1:
                guess = int(input("> "))
                if guess == to_guess:
                    print(FLAG)
                    exit()
                elif guess < to_guess:
                    print("My number is higher!")
                    guess_count -= 1
                else:
                    print("My number is lower!")
                    guess_count -= 1
            elif choice == 2:
                print(f"You lost! My number was {to_guess}")
                break
            if guess_count == 0:
                print(f"You lost! My number was {to_guess}")
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.alarm(TIMEOUT)
    handle()
```

Comment: The number 625 in the loop is interesting. Python's default PRNG is Mersenne Twister which maintains 624 words of state.

Comment: Another issue is finding the **exact** algorithm details used by python's mersenne twister implementation. I'd hate to have to pour through hundreds of lines of C code trying to figure out what exactly is happening internally to get `random.getrandbits(32)` output. Also, if there is even a minor change to this implementation it could throw everything off.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Given that it's a CTF and the FLAG is in plaintext in the code the answer has to be that it's run on some server out of the player's control. Similar to his previous question, standard input and standard output of the above program are connected to the two halves of a socket after you connect to the server with your CTF-solver program.

Comment: Yes, it comes from `os.environ["FLAG"]`. That's the from the environment of python program, which if it were somehow on your own PC would thus be available in plaintext.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't try guessing the first 624 numbers, just give up on them. You're told what they were, feed them into [randcrack](https://github.com/tna0y/Python-random-module-cracker/tree/master) as shown in its example. Ask it to predict the next 32-bit number and guess that.

For a bigger challenge, you could try it without that tool. Here's some insight, "predicting" the next number, i.e., showing how it's computed from the state:

```
import random

for _ in range(5):
    s = random.getstate()[1]
    y = s[s[-1]]
    y ^= (y >> 11);
    y ^= (y << 7) & 0x9d2c5680;
    y ^= (y << 15) & 0xefc60000;
    y ^= (y >> 18);
    print('predict:', y)
    print('actual: ', random.getrandbits(32))
    print()
```

Sample output:

```
predict: 150999088
actual:  3825261045

predict: 457032747
actual:  457032747

predict: 667801614
actual:  667801614

predict: 3817694986
actual:  3817694986

predict: 816636218
actual:  816636218
```

First I get the state, which is 624 words of 32 bits and an index. The calculation of `y` is from [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d6892c2b9263b39ea1c7905667942914b6a24b2c/Modules/_randommodule.c#L155). The first number is wrong because in reality, the first time the more complicated code above it runs.

If you can figure out how to inverse those calculations, you could reconstruct the original state from the given first 624 numbers, then set that state with `random.setstate`, and generate the next number. The tool does seem to do that inversal, but it doesn't look trivial.

Comment: May I ask you if there is a paper or something I can check? I would like to try to understand what's the math behind it. Anyway, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Shark44 I don't know. I guess it would be reasonable to create a GitHub issue for randcrack, asking them to add documentation of how it works.